# Team Fortress 2 won't launch?

Tags: nvidia, games, steam, bumblebee

So, I recently installed Bumblebee on my computer, running 12.04 LTS. I used the optirun command to launch Steam, and it worked just fine. I try to launch Team Fortress 2 within Steam, it'll play one note of the intro video, and then crash. The terminal error reads:

```
The program 'hl2_linux' received an X Window System error.
This probably reflects a bug in the program.
The error was 'BadWindow (invalid Window parameter)'.
  (Details: serial 139 error_code 3 request_code 15 minor_code 0)
  (Note to programmers: normally, X errors are reported asynchronously;
   that is, you will receive the error a while after causing it.
   To debug your program, run it with the --sync command line
   option to change this behavior. You can then get a meaningful
   backtrace from your debugger if you break on the gdk_x_error() function.)
Missing shutdown function for DevShotGenerator_Init() : DevShotGenerator_Shutdown()
Missing shutdown function for MapReslistGenerator_Init() : MapReslistGenerator_Shutdown()
Missing shutdown function for COM_InitFilesystem( m_StartupInfo.m_pInitialMod ) : COM_ShutdownFileSystem()
Missing shutdown function for Steam3Client().Activate() : Steam3Client().Shutdown()
/home/kelerak/.local/share/Steam/SteamApps/common/Team Fortress 2/hl2.sh: line 67:  3248 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) ${GAME_DEBUGGER} "${GAMEROOT}"/${GAMEEXE} "$@"
Game removed: AppID 440 "Team Fortress 2", ProcID 3248
```

And then it goes to repeat this phrase:

```
(steam:2816): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.
```

Does anybody know what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of running all of Steam with optirun I would suggest starting Steam normally and editing the program settings to use the launch command of "optirun %command%" (without the quotes). This will limit the memory of your graphics card to being used only by the game itself. I'm not sure if that will help with the other issues you are having but it may help.

Comment: Using optirun %command% didn't work. Now the game won't launch at all.

Comment: That's strange, if that is the case there may be a problem with your Bumblebee installation. Have you tried running optirun glxgears in a terminal to verify it is workin correctly?

Comment: optirun glxgears runs just fine. I don't know what it is, maybe a problem with the game's code or something.

Comment: Another thing to do for the sake of troubleshooting is to turn off the steam overlay and see if that helps. I know I had problems with the overlay with Bumblebee at one time. What kind of Nvidia card do you have? Also are you using Bumblebee or Bumblebee-nvidia. The open source drivers still aren't quite as good as the nvidia ones so it might not hurt to try switching to that if you're not using it.

Comment: I have an NVIDIA GeForce GT 640m graphics card. I installed the version of Bumblebee I have following the instructions I found here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee

Comment: First I will comment that the support for Optimus hardware is MUCH improved with 14.04 so I would definitely suggest upgrading, but I'm not saying you NEED to. Aside from that, is there any particular reason you're using Bumblebee instead of Nvidia-prime? With Nvidia-Prime you can switch to using the 640m full-time by clicking a toggle and back to the intel chip by switching it back. Using prime over bumblebee helped performance a bunch.

Comment: I just had read somewhere that Bumblebee was the only way to have support for the setup I had. Granted, the article that said that was a couple years old, but I never found anything else that helped. I might look into Nvidia-Prime, though.